# Vue-router: I don't want to use all routes for dynamically creating loop of <router-link>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I dynamically created sidebar navigation list using router-link.

```
<template>
<div class="sidebarListItem bg-light">
    <router-link
       v-for="route in $router.options.routes"
       :key="route.path" 
       :to="route.path"
       class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
       {{route.title}} 
    </router-link>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: "PageSidebarList",
   computed: {
            routes(){
                return this.$router.options.routes
                }
            },  
}          
</script>
```

Each router-link is one map.
But then, I need to use `<router-link>` in some other place in my app, so I need to register new view (map) in router.js. The problem is I don't want this one view to be in sidebar list and it is automatically because of my code. I tried to separate routes in different files(one that I need for list and the rest of the views) and then importem them in router.js. but still it does't work. Or I don't know how to call them separatelly. I am new to vue and vue-router so please help. Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add custom meta data to each route:

```
{
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { hideInNav: true }
}
```

And then you can use a v-if on the router-link `v-if="!route.meta.hideInNav"`

Comment: I understand the idea and yes it seams like good solution, but I can not make it work because I can not put both v-for and v-if under <router-link>. I tried puting v-if in parent div but nothing is happenig as well. Any sugestion for this pls?